# How to share UIMap with in the team in coded UI Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I want to share the objects that have been added to the UIMap, with in my team as they can start programming the coded in visual Studio 2012 so, How can we share the UIMap like the OR in QTP

Thanks

Comment: Use version control for working on shared code in Visual Studio. 
Try learning about TFS or SVN. Once you understand version control it will be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Team Foundation Server version control, the test code can be shared with other team members via the version control.

Comment: Can you please add those steps. How to share in TFS version control

Comment: In Visual Studio, select your test solution, right click and select Add Solution to Source Control from the menu. 

It means that the whole your test solution should be under a source control. You will check in and check out your changes. And other team members will have access to the latest code.

This could be helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/05/26/coded-ui-test-in-a-team-build.aspx